# Bold labels in MFC

Tags: html, visual-c++, mfc, label, bold

I want to create labels in MFC (Static text) that have both **bold** and non-bold text. Something like this:

"I would like my label  **to look like**  this, for example"

Any thoughts of how to do this?

I know that I can change the font of the entire label and have it either bold or not, but is there any way of merging more than one style, or maybe give an html-like label?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Instead of a static control, use a RichEdit control containing appropriately marked up text.

Comment: OK, I used the RichEdit control with Border=False and Transparent=True. Thanks.