# How to create a bold and italic label in MFC?

Tags: c++, mfc, label

Please do not mark it as a dupe of this question just yet:

[Bold labels in MFC](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1881865/bold-labels-in-mfc)

That question does not help me; for some reason I do not see the rich edit control. Instead I believe I have to do it in code. here is a sample I found:

http://www.tech-archive.net/Archive/VC/microsoft.public.vc.mfc/2006-10/msg00245.html

My problem is that I prefer not to re-invent the wheel and test for errors myself or through QA.

***Someone must have implemented this before. Please share your code.***

What I would like to do is:

- Keep the same font size, family, etc. as in the already created label, but make it ***bold and italic*** as well.
- Keep the memory footprint reasonably low (do not create any new unnecessary objects), but do not get the app into an inconsistent state either.

I appreciate your help.

Comment: If you are not using a rich edit control, what kind of control are you using? Static text?

Comment: Yes, a label, aka static text. Thanks for the question.

Comment: Also, I find your "I don't want to do any work, give me the code" attitude to be very rude.

Comment: @Mark, I can understand that. How can I phrase it better? I am just entering into the world of MFC and I have a tight deadline. I am not comfortable with it. I do believe that someone has a very good solution already.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

You will want to do the following before the static text control is shown on the parent window.

1. Get a handle to the window: `CWnd * pwnd = GetDlgItem(IDC_LABEL);`
2. Get the current font for the static text: `CFont * pfont = pwnd->GetFont();`
3. Get the characteristics of the font: `LOGFONT lf; pfont->GetLogFont(&lf);`
4. Change the lfWeight and lfItalic fields in `lf`.
5. Put a CFont object in your parent window, so it will exist for the entire lifetime of the child window.
6. Initialize the CFont: `m_font.CreateFontIndirect(&lf);`
7. Set the font into the static text window: `pwnd->SetFont(&m_font);`

Comment: Turns out, I also need to call a DeleteObject() on the font. http://social.msdn.microsoft.com/Forums/en-US/Vsexpressvc/thread/69089425-f186-47fe-9c32-baa29ac2a50c

Comment: Nope, that was also a bad idea.

Comment: MFC will call DeleteObject automatically when the CFont object is destroyed.

Comment: #5 was crucial for my issue. I should have figured that out. Thank you for your detail post.